# When I hover over text I lose hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover

You can see when you hover around the text, you'll see hover effect, but when you hover directly over text you lose that effect.

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="work1"></div>
<p style="position: absolute; top: 2px;">Brand new logo!</p>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#work1 {
    width: 308px;
    height: 86px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #272727;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
    -o-transition: 0.3s all;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}

#work1:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mda1Ld2o/

Comment: Updated my answer to fix the opacity problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mda1Ld2o/3/)

Your `<p>` is outside the `<div>`

```
<div id="work1">
    <p>Brand new logo!</p>
</div>
```

but that's not all that needs fixing. You're trying to animate the bg color, not the opacity. Try this css instead:

```
#work1 {
    width: 308px;
    height: 86px;
    background-color: transparent;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
    -o-transition: 0.3s all;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}

#work1:hover {
    background-color: #272727;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is using `pointer-events: none;` on the absolute positioned element, the paragraph as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/mda1Ld2o/6/)**

```css
p {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

According to **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)**:

> The CSS property `pointer-events` allows authors to control under what
>   circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the
>   target of mouse events.
>
> **none:**
>   The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse
>   events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse
>   events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases

`pointer-event` is [documented in SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty), however it can be used for HTML/XML contents.

Comment: +1 Because this is a neat trick for negating the effects of an absolutely positioned element! However, -1 because this is needlessly complex. You solve the issue without really taking into consideration what the OP is really trying to do and his/her obviously new entry into HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You had the

```
<p>
```

outside the

```
<div>
```

.

```
<div id="work1">
  <p style="position: absolute; top: 2px;">Brand new logo!</p>
</div>
```

And I made the `color:white` on hover. So you can read...

```
#work1:hover {
  background-color: #272727;
  color:white;
}
```

## JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/mda1Ld2o/8/

Comment: Yes, but then I don't see text at all. Only when hover.

Comment: Ok, that's a problem. You can either push the `p` inside the `opacity:0` `div` OR have a hover effect with wrapping it with the `div`. Your decision. Your question was solved :o

Comment: ^ Not so. There are other options.

Answer (score 0):

You `p` tag needs to be inside the `div`

That's why the hover is off

As for the opacity. I used this [site](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm) to convert your hex color to rgb which results to `27,27,27`

So change your css to:

```
#work1 {
    width: 308px;
    height: 86px;
    background-color: rgba(27,27,27,0);
    -moz-transition: 0.3s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
    -o-transition: 0.3s all;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}

#work1:hover {
    background-color: rgba(27,27,27,1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="work1">
  <p style="position: absolute; top: 2px;">Brand new logo!</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Works great then opacity is set to 0 :P.

Comment: @Tom so the question is not so specific but I get what is to happen. Will update

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because your `p` tag is outside of the `div#work1`. Put your paragraph into div.

```
<div id="work1">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 2px;">Brand new logo!</p>
</div>
```

You might have change a `color` of your text.

```
color: #FFF;
```